# Disable Stacking ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to put on barchart in front of another (I'm using alphas to convey information)

In ggplot2 if I do `ggplot() + geom_bar() + geom_bar()` I end up with a stacked bar chart, not one layer in front of the other. How do I change/disable this?

```
TPlot = ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = 1:3, y=c(1,1,1), width=0.1),stat="identity", alpha=0, colour = "red",position="identity") +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y")

for (i in 1:3){
  TPlot = TPlot + geom_bar(aes(x = 1:3, y = c(i,i,i), width=0.1),stat="identity", position="identity", alpha=0.2)
}

TPlot
```

I was hoping to see darker regions where more bars were being drawn, but that's not the case.

Comment: You set `position = "identity"`?

Comment: Nope, that's not working for me. I'll provide more code, hang on.

Comment: `position = "identity"` is working, but something else is going wrong, possibly related to all the non-standard (and inadvisable) things you're doing here inside `aes()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot understand why but it seems that something strange with `for` loop. The code below works well. But when I try to use a `for` loop only the last `geom_bar` is added.

```
TPlot = ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = 1:3, y=c(1,1,1), width=0.1),stat="identity", alpha=0.2,
           position="identity") +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y")

TPlot = TPlot + geom_bar(aes(x = 1:3, y = c(2,2,2), width=0.1),
                         stat="identity", position="identity", alpha=0.2)
TPlot = TPlot + geom_bar(aes(x = 1:3, y = c(3,3,3), width=0.1),
                         stat="identity", position="identity", alpha=0.2)

TPlot
```

[image]

With `for` loop.

```
TPlot = ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = 1:3, y=c(1,1,1), width=0.1),stat="identity", alpha=0.2, 
           position="identity") +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y")

for (i in 2:3){
  TPlot = TPlot + geom_bar(aes(x = 1:3, y = c(i,i,i), width=0.1),
                           stat="identity", position="identity", alpha=0.2)
}

TPlot
```

[image]

This code works. It results in a picure indentical to the first one. Thanks to joran.

```
TPlot = ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = 1:3, y=c(1,1,1), width=0.1),stat="identity", alpha=0.2, 
           position="identity") +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y")

for (i in c(2,3)){
  TPlot = TPlot + geom_bar(data=data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c(i,i,i)),
                           aes(x=x, y=y, width=0.1), 
                           stat="identity", alpha=0.2)
}

TPlot
```

Comment: Ah, well I'm planning to add around 250 plots, so I need the for loop! Any guesses as to how to get this to work?

Comment: @N.McA. My best guess here is that, as always, it's a bad idea to ask ggplot to resolve variable names that aren't in a provided data frame. That's what you're doing here with `i`. Something about the functional nature of how the `for` loop is parsed is preventing ggplot from seeing each individual `i` value I think, so they are all getting the last value.

Comment: No, but it looks that in the `for` loop last `geom_bar` is drawn twice and the darker color is obtained like for `y = 2` on the first chart.

Answer (score 3):

"`aes()` creates a list of unevaluated expressions", according to its help page, so in your for loop you end up with layers that are identical because they refer to a variable name "i" which was not evaluated. When ggplot finally builds the layers, it uses whatever value of i is around (more specifically, it can look in the optional `environment` if you give one). But that doesn't work here, because you wanted different values of i for each layer. You could use substitute() or bquote() in the loop, but it's better to construct a new data.frame for each layer. Or better yet, create a single data.frame with your loop, with a variable to keep track of which step it refers to. You can then using aesthetic mapping and/or facetting, which is more in line with what ggplot2 is designed for (and more efficient than having many independent layers).